# How to extract certain words from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array that was given to me to use:

```
const databaseEntry = ['Faction: First Galactic Empire', 'Name: Firms Piett', 'Rank: Admiral'];
```

And my task is to create a variable from this array that ends up like this

```
'Firms Piett, Admiral of the First Galactic Empire.'
```

I have tried and retried, but I'm still new with arrays

Comment: You'll get better results here if you edit the question to show what you've tried, even if it doesn't work yet.

Comment: What did you tried ? Please included in the question

Answer (score 1):

Re-organize your data as an object so as to have more simple key-value associations, then build your sentence:

```js
const foo = entry => {
  const o = {};
  for(let e of entry) {
    let [key, value] = e.split(': ');
    o[key]=value;
  }
  return `${o.Name}, ${o.Rank} of the ${o.Faction}`;
}

console.log(foo(['Faction: First Galactic Empire', 'Name: Firms Piett', 'Rank: Admiral']));
```

Since you're a beginner, you might need to check out [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to fully understand the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Loop through each item in the array, and split on the space. This will get you an array of two values for each item. For example, `["Faction:", "First Galactic Empire"]`. Then you can just use the index values to get the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

```js
const databaseEntry = ['Faction: First Galactic Empire', 'Name: Firms Piett', 'Rank: Admiral'];

let faction = databaseEntry[0].split(": ")[1]
let name = databaseEntry[1].split(": ")[1]
let rank = databaseEntry[2].split(": ")[1]

console.log(`${name}, ${rank} of the ${faction}.`)

// Since you asked for the final lenght:
console.log(`${name}, ${rank} of the ${faction}.`.length)

// => You can add the '.length' attribute to any String ("Hello World".length)
```

This is an easy solution for your problem. And since you seem to be new to JavaScript this is probably the best thing to do to help you to understand arrays :)

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me and the answer, this seems to be an awesome community. In the end I have to do a console.log of the length of it, but I don't see a variable to use the .length. How should I do it?

Comment: @JoséCorreia I edited my answer to show the final length at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Really simple one-liner with `map`, `split` and array destructuring.

```js
const databaseEntry = ['Faction: First Galactic Empire', 'Name: Firms Piett', 'Rank: Admiral'];

const [faction, name, rank] = databaseEntry.map(e => e.split(": ")[1]);

console.log(`${name}, ${rank} of the ${faction}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the the answer . In the end I have to do a console.log of the length of it, but I don't see a variable to use the .length. How should I do it?